# What does the X-MultipleArgs in the Desktop Entry file mean?

Tags: desktop, gnome, kde-plasma, freedesktop.org

All of the sample Desktop files have X-MultipleArgs=False --- but what does this mean?  The X- means it's an extension so it's not defined in the FreeDesktop specification.   But I can't seem to find a place where it is defined.  Google searches don't help since it turns up lots of Desktop files.

Comment: As seen in [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1777584), when I add that to a desktop entry it makes a web page to launch in a different icon, instead on the Chromium one. But I don't know if that's a side effect, or the wanted behaviour.